# What is $0.5!×(-0.5)!$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Based on the answers and help given, as$$
0.5!= \sqrt{π}, \quad (-0.5)!= \sqrt{π},
$$
thus the product is $π$. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

If one interprets $x!$ as $\Gamma(x+1)$ where $\Gamma$ denotes the [Gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function), then $(-1/2)!=\Gamma(1/2)=\sqrt\pi$ and $(1/2)!=\Gamma(3/2)=\sqrt\pi/2$. Therefore
$$(-1/2)!(1/2)!=\frac\pi2.$$